# vimeo - video request API oauth_timestamp issue

Tags: json, video, response, vimeo

I am creating web application using struts framework with WASCE server. In that I want to load the **vimeo** videos when the user enter their username. So that I have created the application in vimeo developer site and got the apiKey, apiSecret, token and secret values. I have applied these values into my code. I got the correct(with video urls) JSON response when I run in local.

But Whan I deployed it into the deticated server and check the response I got,

```
{"generated_in":"0.0039","stat":"fail","err":{"code":"401","expl":"The oauth_timestamp 
passed is either too far in the past or in the future. Vimeo thinks the current time is 
1379053244","msg":"Invalid \/ expired token"}}
```

I have searched about this issue and got some solution as follows.

```
Looks like your server's time is set incorrectly. Vimeo's API is time-sensitive to 
within a few minutes. You should be able to ask your hosting provider to 
correct the server's time.
```

Ref: http://community.tubepress.com/topic/287-vimeo-no-videos-to-populate-this-tubepress-gallery/?p=989

So that I have checked server time. My local time is 11.00AM, Server Time is 23.00PM. Now I changed the server time to 11.00AM(Because 11.00AM is working in localhost).

But Still I am getting the same issue. Can anyone tell me what may be the problem and how can I fix this.

**Note:**
I have changed the local time to 23:00PM and I got that "Invalid expired token" resonse. So again change it to 11.00AM, I got a correct response.

Comment: To get to the bottom of this issue, I think I need more information about the requests you are making. Unfortunately this could involve secret tokens. If you contact me through https://vimeo.com/help/contact I should be able to help track down your problem. Once we have solved the issue I'll post back here so the answer is available to the public.

Comment: @Dashron: Thanks for the response. I have posted the question in https://vimeo.com/help/contact. But I got the following reply email. "Unfortunately, Vimeo does not offer in-depth support for using our API or building custom applications beyond locating and troubleshooting bugs." For your reference this is Case #: 278111

Comment: @Dashron: We got this from mail. If you have additional questions about the Vimeo APIs, we recommend posting your inquiry on Stack Overflow. 
The folks in the Stack Overflow community are great at troubleshooting tricky API situations..

Comment: @Dashron: Can you help me to fix this issue?